# Disconnect process from Linux console

Tags: linux, debian, process, gnu-screen, connection

I have a long-running process that was started in bash terminal on Debian. Unfortunately it wasn't started inside screen.
Is there a way to disconnect this process from current console and connect to it from screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to transfer ownership.

If all you want is to keep the process active while log out (and you're using bash), suspend the process with ^Z, then "disown -h" to release it from your shell.

Comment: So will it be running in background?

Comment: Yes, but you will be unable to attach to it if you kill your current shell.